# VBA - Sorting cells referencing MergeArea

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am running into an issue with my sorting code.  My goal is to sort area by address type. Each person has multiple accounts and there name is in a merged area that goes as long as there are accounts.  So from "B3:B6" is merged for the first one.

However, sometimes these people have different addresses under each account. So, i'd like to sort each area, in this example "C3:H6" by the values in Column E.  But, when I run through line-by-line, it doesn't execute it.

**CODE:**

```
With NeedMail
    rwCnt = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For y = 3 To rwCnt
        If .Cells(y, 2).MergeCells Then
            Set mrg = .Range(.Cells(y, 2).MergeArea.Address)
            Set srt = .Range(mrg.Offset(0, 1).Address & ":" & mrg.Offset(0, 6).Address)
            Set keyRng = .Range(mrg.Offset(0, 3).Address)
            cnt = .Cells(y, 2).MergeArea.Rows.Count
            Z = y + cnt - 1

            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=keyRng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With .Sort
                .SetRange srt
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With

            mrg.UnMerge

        'More code to execute here

        End If
    Next y
End With
```

**SAMPLE DATA:**

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

Thank you in advance, I've been racking my brain trying to figure what is wrong?

Comment: A screenshot with sample data would be helpful here. Also, column A is merged, right, so why do you check `If .Cells(y, 2).MergeCells`?

Comment: @BigBen - Sorry, I fixed it, it is actually column B that is merged. Let me edit some data and then I will post a screenshot

Comment: @BigBen - I added sample data into my question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you offset `mrg`, e.g. `Set srt = .Range(mrg.Offset(0, 1)...`, your newly offset range is only 1 row high. So `Resize` the number of rows using `cnt`.

Also, once you have `srt`, you can just use `srt.Sort`.
Here's revised code showing that simplified sort.

```
Sub SortWhenMerged()
    Dim needMail As Worksheet
    Dim rwCnt As Long, y As Long, cnt As Long
    Dim mrg As Range, srt As Range, keyRng As Range

    Set needMail = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NeedMail")
    With needMail
        rwCnt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

        For y = 3 To rwCnt
            If .Cells(y, 2).MergeCells Then

                Set mrg = .Cells(y, 2).MergeArea
                cnt = mrg.Rows.Count

                Set srt = mrg.Offset(, 1).Resize(cnt, 6)
                Set keyRng = mrg.Offset(, 3).Resize(cnt)

                srt.Sort Key1:=keyRng, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, SortMethod:=xlPinYin

                mrg.UnMerge
            End If
        Next y
    End With

End Sub
```